# MySQL: How to select records for this week?

Tags: mysql, date

I have table `temp` with structure on [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf1aa):

```
id(int 11 primary key)
name(varchar 100)
name2(varchar 100)
date(datetime)
```

I would like get record on this week, example if now 21.11.2013 i would like all rows on 18.11.2013 to 24.11.2013(on week)

Now I see next algorithm:

1. obtain weekday
2. calculate how many days ago was Monday
3. calculate the date Monday
4. calculate future date Sunday
5. make a request on date

Tell me please, is exist a shorter algorithm (preferably in the query MySQL)?

**ADD Question is:** Why [**this query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf1aa/1)  select record on date `17.11.2013(Sunday) - 23.11.2013(Saturday)` and how get records on date `18.11.2013(Monday) - 24.11.2013(Sunday)` ?

query:

```
select * from temp
where yearweek(`date`) = yearweek(curdate())
```

Thanks!

Comment: you tried something???

Comment: @Mayank you dont see? i write algorithm find. or neee write coe with algorithm?

Comment: @YourCommonSense tell me please why you elete tag mysqli?

Comment: tell me please what your question has to do with mysqli?

Comment: @YourCommonSense i think that question for mysql an mysqli

Comment: I see not a single word related to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok, thanks for information, i will be know on future

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use [`YEARWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Comment: what is best? WEEKOFYEAR or yearweek ?

Comment: with `yearweek()` you can specify an additional parameter on which day a week starts.

Comment: tell me please why it query select record on date 17.11.2013(Sunday) - 23.11.2013(Saturday) and how get records on date 18.11.2013(Monday) - 24.11.2013(Sunday) ?

Comment: Use a specific mode like `1`. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Comment: Note that this method may not be efficient if `date` is indexed. The DB won't be able to use the index. You need a condition that starts with e.g. `date` > = ...

Answer (score 16):

Use `YEARWEEK`. If you use `WEEKOFYEAR` you will get records of previous years also.

```
SELECT id, name, date
FROM table
WHERE YEARWEEK(date)=YEARWEEK(NOW());
```

Comment: what is best? WEEKOFYEAR or yearweek ?

Comment: Use YEARWEEK.. If you use WEEKOFYEAR you will get records of previous years also..Edited my ans

Answer (score 6):

For selecting records of day, week and month use this way:

```
function my_func($time, $your_date) {
if ($time == 'today') {
    $timeSQL = ' Date($your_date)= CURDATE()';
}
if ($time == 'week') {
    $timeSQL = ' YEARWEEK($your_date)= YEARWEEK(CURDATE())';
}
if ($time == 'month') {
    $timeSQL = ' Year($your_date)=Year(CURDATE()) AND Month(`your_date`)= Month(CURDATE())';
}

$Sql = "SELECT * FROM  your_table WHERE ".$timeSQL
return $Result = $this->db->query($Sql)->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following method

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%U");
```

Get number of week (From 00 to 53 ) 
Where (Sunday 1st day and Monday last day of week)

May be useful for you.

example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT('dates', '%U') AS weekdays FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short solution would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT("2021-08-19 15:40:33", "%U") = WEEK(CURDATE());
```