# Select rows from current week

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `posts` table with field `post_date`, field type `DATETIME`, which records when the record was added in `UTC`. I have a section on the webpage where posts of the current week is shown. The week starts on **Monday** and the time zone used to display date/time on the website is `Asia/Calcutta`. I'm using the following queries to fetch the *posts this week*:

```
SET time_zone = '+0:00'
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE YEARWEEK( post_date, 1 ) = YEARWEEK( CURDATE(), 1 ) );
```

But it's getting me posts from previous week as well.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to select records for this week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120693/mysql-how-to-select-records-for-this-week)